# Chat schema for PostgreSQL and MongoDB

Tags: postgresql, mongodb, schema

[image: Chat schema for PostgreSQL and MongoDB]

I'm designing a schema for a very large chat app. I had problems with NoSQL databases such as MongoDB and Cassandra. Some part of the schema is relational i decided to use both PostgreSQL and MongoDB together.

Chats and members are stored in PostgreSQL and messages are stored in MongoDB.
There is a table called events in both databases. i just keep chat_ids and creation time of the events in PostgreSQL and the data of events in MongoDB.
These events include `remove_message` `block_user` , etc.

Note that `longtext` means `json`

**Questions**
What problems do i face if i use both together?
Is there anything to change?

## *Updated*

**Message schema**

```js
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  user_id: Number,
  chat_id: Number,
  random_id: String,
  peer: {
    type: [Number],
    default: []
  }
  message: String,
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["service-message", "text", "image", "video", "voice"]
  },
  reply_to: {
    message_id: ObjectId,
    user_id: Number
  },
  forwarded_from: {
    message_id: ObjectId,
    user_id: Number,
    chat_id: Number,
  }
  deleted_for: {
    type: [Number],
    default: []
  },
  author_signature: String,
  restriction_reason: String,
  number_of_forwards: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  is_read: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  is_deleted: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  is_private: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  },
  is_edited: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  created_at: {
    type: Number,
    default: Date.now
  },
  updated_at: {
    type: Number,
    default: Date.now
  }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that by using two very different data stores for no reason you are doubling your maintenance overhead and increasing the possibility of performance and availability problems, particulary when serving "a very large chat app".

Comment: What benefit do you think you get from using a NoSQL database? It sounds like most (and probably all) of your schema is relational, so with the details provided so far, I don't see why you would have a need for MongoDB.

Comment: @J.D. I think storing messages in a relational database is bad idea. MongoDB is faster in this case. Also the messages are unstructured. Sharding is easier for MongoDB.  In another question we talked about it before. it]s a write heavy app this is what MongoDB is good at. Let me know if i'm wrong.

Comment: @mustaccio I have many questions, some people say go with MongoDB, Cassandra some say go with MySQL, PostgreSQL. This is confusing. Articles say for very large data use NoSQL, so the large part of the app is the messages table/collection.

Comment: PostgreSQL has some pretty impressive JSON capabilites - best of both worlds?

Comment: Please note that there's a lot of confusing one-sided information out there that say "*for very large data use NoSQL*" but without mentioning why in the best case, and in the worst case incorrectly claiming for "performance" reasons. They are either subjective or just plain wrong. Data is data, 1 GB of data isn't going to be faster to locate and load off disk and return to a client consuming application regardless if you store it in a relational database or a NoSQL one. Again talking from experience having worked with 10s of billions / terabytes of `Messages` data myself.

Comment: By the way, does your chat app generate the `Message` data?...if so, why not store it in a relational way from the beginning instead of as a single denormalized object? If you have control over how the message object is created, then you're already ahead of the game to be able to store in a normalized form in a relational database. My past experience was working with external data I received as messages, and had to ingest into my database, so that was obviously harder since I was being given a denormalized object from the start, but it still worked fine converting it to a relational model.

Comment: @J.D. Yes, the message object won't change for a long time. I had another question not related to the topic, is the auto-increment feature in RDBMS fast enough to generate thousands of ids per second? I think i should have my own id generator independent to other records. By the way i don't have enough reputation, i would upvote all your answers. Thank you.

Comment: No problem! Auto-increment / identity specifications are optimized to generate values in a negligible amount of time. I don't think there's any specific information out there on the exact time, but it's safe to say it would take no more than a few milliseconds to generate thousands of values. I would definitely not worry about the performance of using auto-increment, and wouldn't recommend trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Data type should be `Date` instead of `Number`  for date values.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit In most cases i need Unix Timestamps not date/time.

Comment: @Jacqueline Did you end up going with a single postgreSQL database? Reading everything on this page was very helpful and it seems like that is the suggestion by most, but just curious how you ended up implementing it as I'm also encountering a similar decision with an AI chat app. First I thought I needed Cassandra with pg but astradb (cassandra with datastax) was quite unsupported, and then I thought Mongodb would be good instead to store threads and messages, and after reading this... thinking maybe postgres for it is fine to reduce complexity... what did you end up with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This hopefully indirectly answers your question and points you in the right direction, it's too much to discuss in comments:

### NoSQL Use Case History

MongoDB is not any more performant with writing data than any other mainstream relational database (PostgreSQL, SQL Server, etc). The same is true for reading data as well. NoSQL was not invented to be more performant with reading, writing, or querying data, rather it was originally created to be a tool to improve developer speed especially with a highly changing or variable schema. By not having to worry about maintaining an object structure both in the data layer in addition to the application layer, NoSQL databases allowed developers with specific development needs to release software changes faster when managing a highly changing schema.

From what I can see, your `messages` entity is structured but perhaps the content of the message text is not (an example of the text would be helpful). Regardless you can either parse the text into a relational model or store it as a single text field just the same as your entity currently is modeled as, if you wanted to use a relational database system for all of your data.

### Sharding, Not Even Once (or Eight Times)

Sharding *may* be easier (spoiler alert - it's usually not) but at the general tradeoff of eventual consistency (two instances of the same table being out of sync at a given point in time). When to use Sharding depends on a couple of factors generally based on a function of what one is willing to pay to provision their servers vs how much data they need to store, based on their specific use cases. But in general, modern relational database systems handle big data well when architected properly, and I've yet to find Sharding any more useful than vertical scaling.

In fact, the developers of MongoDB themselves state that you're usually better off vertically scaling (as is tradition in a RDBMS) than using Sharding because Sharding is typically more expensive, complex, less flexible, and harder to manage. Per ["*Myth 5: MongoDB is All About Sharding*"](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/everything-you-know-is-wrong/):

> ...a minimum sharded cluster is eight servers, and it goes up by at least three servers, with each shard added.
>
> Sharded clusters also make your data harder to manage, and they add some limitations to the types of queries you can conduct. **Sharding is useful if you need it, but it's often cheaper and easier to simply upgrade your hardware!**
>
> ...If you're attempting to scale by sharding, you should at least consider whether hardware upgrades would be a more efficient alternative, first.

That article written by a MongoDB developer actually further discusses a similar thought process I have, which is many times Sharding is more expensive than vertically scaling. This is because typically the hardware bottleneck is not due to the entire provisioning of the server rather it's due to one or two specific pieces of hardware. So it's cheaper to vertically upgrade just those targeted pieces of hardware as opposed to redundantly buying more servers where you're paying for the other pieces of hardware that weren't the bottleneck. With a properly setup Sharded instance in MongoDB, this would be 8x over one would be redundantly paying for hardware. And then licensing costs become a consideration too, where one may end up needing to pay for more licensing for each server (both at the OS level and / or the database level) when they wouldn't've needed to had they vertically scaled instead.

### My Experiences

All of that being said, I've worked with `Messages` data (financial trading messages) in a large and heavily transactional relational database as well. Some of the tables were into the 10s of billions of rows and multi-terabytes big for a single table. We stored our raw unparsed `Messages` in one table as they came into our system, but wrote an application that also parsed the relevant information from the `Messages` into a normalized table.

### Challenges of Multiple Database Systems

The main three challenges you'll find by using two different databases systems is:

1. Management of the data in two different systems, especially as your data grows: The management of a NoSQL database system requires different thought, planning, and attention than a relational database system.
2. Relating the data across systems in a meaningful way: Consuming the data by your apps or for reporting purposes becomes more complicated and dependent on two unrelated systems. Associating the correlating `messages` data to your other data such as `users` becomes more complicated, and actually probably less efficient since you need two different methodologies for retrieving data which will result in more steps associating the data. For example if you wanted to get the `users.full_name` for the `messages` they created.
3. Timing issues with querying the data as it's still being stored into two different database systems, or even just with synchronizing across Shards in MongoDB itself, with it's eventual consistency implementation. Especially with trying to reconcile analytics between both database systems, it'll become difficult.

### Final Thoughts

Most modern relational database systems can store, parse, and query "*unstructured*" data too, since that's really a subset of structured data. For example, the JSON capabilities of PostgreSQL that Vérace mentions makes it a powerful data store for relational data and any additional meta-data that's unstructured as well.

Alternatively, it seems like your `messages` structure is in your application's control. If that's true, then you don't need to store it all as a single denormalized object. Rather you can store it into the database as a normalized series of tables that make up all of the data from the `messages`. It appears all of your data could be stored in a relational database.

Comment: I added the message schema to the question.

Comment: Thank you, Your answer was very helpful.

Comment: Regarding *I've yet to find Sharing any more useful than vertical scaling.*: I have an application running on Oracle which writes around 4.5 billion records every day (up to 80k every Second). Data size is around 100TB. Currently it is still running fine, however scalability is quite limited. When I double the computing power, then the performance improves maybe by 30% only. In Mongo when I add computing nodes then the performance increases more or less linearly. Because of that, we plan to migrate to MongoDB in future. Of course, it runs also fine on Oracle, but the price tag will be higher.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit You're certainly a good real world example, exceeding the amount of big data I've had the chance to play with. It would be interesting what the long term measurement in cost of server provisioning totals for you when working in MongoDB which is what I generalized about when I said "*what one is willing to pay to provision their servers*". Of course the cost of enterprise software Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, etc is easily beatable by non-enterprise and free alternatives. Though then there's PostgreSQL and MySQL which makes it not a matter of SQL vs NoSQL in software costs.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit That being said, if you're only seeing roughly a 30% improvement in performance when doubling the hardware behind your current system, that sounds like an issue outside of the Oracle SQL software itself, which should always have a linear function in computational abilities to hardware behind it, up to the limitation of the software - which I would assume is data well into the trillions of records and perhaps petabytes in total size. I wouldn't doubt the biggest bottleneck you're seeing is either related to how you architected your system or the infrastructure itself.

Comment: Data must be stored for 6 Months, then it is dropped. So totally I have around "only" 700 billion records. Main cost driver is the storage. Thanks to [bucket pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-bucket-pattern) I need to buy only 35TB of storage when using MongoDB. Architecture can be a challenge when you have such high data rate. Even products which have "fast" in their product name (e.g. "[RSYSLOG](https://www.rsyslog.com/) is the **r**ocket-fast **sys**tem for **log** processing.") are way too slow.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Certainly interesting information, but the bucket pattern is achievable in a relational database as well. Pre-aggregations and data rollups to minimize the amount of underlying raw data are not new concepts when talking data warehousing. Aside from that, the bucket pattern seems to save space by not redundantly storing data, but that's also naturally occurring in most RDBMS as well with their native compression and even additional row, column, and table compression features. At the disk level the data would be stored the same.

Comment: This is a very interesting conversation and I'm certainly learning some new methodologies for managing data, but we should continue it [in a chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133670) if you wouldn't mind, since comments aren't really supposed to be used for discussion. I think you have a lot of good real world experience and insight. 